# Python Flask returning a Not Found error despite route being defined

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am making an ecommerce app and the when the checkout form is submitted, I am getting the error

Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

However, the route I want to send the user to (`pending.html`) is defined and workout outside of the checkout page.

Here are the routes for '`/checkout`' and `'/pending'` in my `views.py` file.

```
@views.route('/checkout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checkout():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        course_id = request.form.get('course_id')
        course = Item.query.filter_by(id=course_id).first_or_404()

        # Validate form data
        required_fields = ['p_first_name', 'p_last_name', 'p_email', 'p_address', 'p_country', 'p_state', 'p_zip', 'p_card_name', 'p_cc_number', 'p_cc_exp', 'p_cvv']
        for field in required_fields:
            if not request.form.get(field):
                flash('Please fill in all required fields.', category='error')
                return redirect(url_for('views.checkout', course_id=course_id))

        p_first_name = request.form.get('p_first_name')
        p_last_name = request.form.get('p_last_name')
        p_email = request.form.get('p_email')
        p_address = request.form.get('p_address')
        p_address_2 = request.form.get('p_address_2')
        p_country = request.form.get('p_country')
        p_state = request.form.get('p_state')
        p_zip = request.form.get('p_zip')
        p_save = request.form.get('p_save')
        p_card_name = request.form.get('p_card_name')
        p_cc_number = request.form.get('p_cc_number')
        p_cc_exp = request.form.get('p_cc_exp')
        p_cvv = request.form.get('p_cvv')

        new_purchase = Purchase(p_first_name=p_first_name, p_last_name=p_last_name, p_email=p_email, p_address=p_address, p_address_2=p_address_2, p_country=p_country, p_state=p_state, p_zip=p_zip, p_save=p_save, p_card_name=p_card_name, p_cc_number=p_cc_number, p_cc_exp=p_cc_exp, p_cvv=p_cvv)
        db.session.add(new_purchase)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('views.pending'))
    else:
        course_id = request.args.get('course_id')
        course = Item.query.filter_by(id=course_id).first_or_404()
    return render_template('checkout.html', user=current_user, course=course)


@views.route('/pending', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pending():
    return render_template('pending.html', user=current_user)
```

And here is the HTML file for `checkout.html`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Checkout{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="text-center">
<h2>Complete Your Purchase</h2>
<h3>You want to buy {{ course.course }}</h3>
    <h3>Price: ${{ course.price }}</h3>
</div>


<form class="card p-2">
    <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
    <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="p_first_name" placeholder="" value="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Valid first name is required. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="p_last_name" placeholder="" value="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Valid last name is required. </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted"></span></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="p_email" placeholder="you@example.com">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="p_address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required="">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter your shipping address. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="address2">Address 2 <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" name="p_address_2" placeholder="Apartment or suite">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" name="country" required="">
                    <option value="">Choose...</option>
                    <option>United States</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please select a valid country. </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="state">State</label>

            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" name="state" required="">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
            </select>


                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid state. </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Zip code required. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="save-info" name="p_save">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="save-info">Save this information for next time</label>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>
        <div class="d-block my-3">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" checked="" required="">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required="">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="cc-name">Name on card</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" name="p_card_name" placeholder="" required="">
                <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Name on card is required </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" p="p_cc_number" placeholder="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Credit card number is required </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="cc-expiration">Expiration</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" name="p_cc_exp" placeholder="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Expiration date required </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="p_cvv" placeholder="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Security code required </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
    </form>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried to rewrite the route, redirect to a different page, and check server logs. None of these fix the problem.

Comment: On the HTML file I can't see anything that would redirect the user to /checkout (either on the form action or an anchor tag). How do you redirect the user through the button?

Comment: Doesn't it redirect from the checkout route after the info is put in the db? Should I amend the button then?

Comment: Yes it should, what am I pointing out is the checkout button when clicked doesn't seem to go to /checkout. Are there anything like ``` /checkout - 404 ``` on your server log?